# Python install package via pip3: Segmentation fault

Tags: python, pip

I want to use `pip3` to install python packages. For example, if I do `pip3 install matplotlib`, it gives me:

```
Collecting matplotlib
Segmentation fault
```

I have my `pip3` and `python3.6` installed:

```
which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

which python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

And I tried `sudo pip3 install matplotlib`, it showed:

```
The directory '/home/shiqi/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

I changed the `.cache` directory to be available to all:

```
chmod +rwx .cache

drwxr-xr-x 17 shiqi shiqi  4096 Jan  4 14:45 .cache
```

I am not sure why it is not writable to everybody, but at least user has the write to write to `.cache`. But this did not solve my segmentation fault problem. Does anyone know what to do? Thank you!

Comment: Is that all the error output you get?

Comment: Yes, that's all I got.